# Induction in geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, induction

There is an intriguingly titled book by Golovina and Yaglom called [Induction in geometry](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=138022), which I found referenced in [Uspensky - A curious case of the use of mathematical induction in geometry](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1927.11986694).  It is in Russian, and was translated into [Spanish](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=451159), but I cannot find an English translation.  Does one exist?

If not, is there any good place to look for an English treatment of the subject of Golovina and Yaglom's book?

Comment: https://store.doverpublications.com/0486838560.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Published by Dover:

Induction in Geometry discusses the application of the method of mathematical induction to the solution of geometric problems, some of which are quite intricate. The book contains 37 examples with detailed solutions and 40 for which only brief hints are provided. Most of the material requires only a background in high school algebra and plane geometry; chapter six assumes some knowledge of solid geometry, and the text occasionally employs formulas from trigonometry. Chapters are self-contained, so readers may omit those for which they are unprepared.
To provide additional background, this volume incorporates the concise text, The Method of Mathematical Induction. This approach introduces this technique of mathematical proof via many examples from algebra, geometry, and trigonometry, and in greater detail than standard texts. A background in high school algebra will largely suffice; later problems require some knowledge of trigonometry. The combination of solved problems within the text and those left for readers to work on, with solutions provided at the end, makes this volume especially practical for independent study.

Reprint of Induction in Geometry and The Method of Mathematical Induction, D. C. Heath and Company, Boston, 1963.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know if a user is notified when an answer is *unaccepted*, but, if so, I apologise:  I clicked and, due to a slow computer, thought it hadn't 'taken', so clicked again just as the first click finally registered.  I think I finally got it to its correct, accepted status.

Comment: You provided the link [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236137/induction-in-geometry/4236184#comment8802665_4236137), but just to have it here:  [Golovina and Yaglom - Induction in Geometry](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486838560.html).  I wonder why this doesn't have a MathSciNet review?—or does it and I just missed it?